# get date retrofit:2.3.0 headers(no string-Date Format)

Tags: android, retrofit2

```
   @Override
   public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<ConfigurationData> call, @NonNull Response<ConfigurationData> response) {

    CacheDb db = new CacheDb(this);
    int statusCode = response.code();
    ConfigurationData configData = response.body();
    String dateString = response.headers().get("date");//date String
    Date date = ..............//***I want this code***

    switch (statusCode){
        case 200:
            db.setClass("config", configData);
            startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, HomePage.class));
            handler.removeCallbacks(null);
            handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
            SplashActivity.this.finish();
            finish();
            break;
        default:
            setDialog();
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<ConfigurationData> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
    setDialog();
}
```

I need date "UTC" from different server PHP Do not create a problem by changing the server. date string is different sample format and me not know What format to use?
***I apologize for saying that English is not good***

Comment: It is not clear what your problem is.